# PHP FPDF/FPDI, Hebrew characters are reversed/mirrored. Can it be fixed?

Tags: php, character-encoding, fpdf

I'm using the `setasign\FPDI` library in PHP to generate PDF documents and all of my documents are in Hebrew.

I am receiving the Hebrew characters in UTF-8 and converting them to cp1255, then adding a Hebrew font to FPDF and everything renders great, only the Hebrew words are reversed/mirrored.

I test to see if the string contains Hebrew letters, if so, I use `strrev()` to reverse it, but if the string contains also phone numbers or other non-hebrew words, it's getting reversed too.

These are my methods for formatting Hebrew for FPDF:

```
/**
 * Utility to check if the string is in Hebrew
 * @param string $string
 * @return int|false
*/
protected function isHebrew(string $string)
{
    if (!$string) return false;
    // return strlen($string) != strlen(utf8_decode($string));
    return preg_match("/\p{Hebrew}/u", $string);
}

/**
 * Utility to format a string to be used with FPDF.
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
*/
protected function formatString(string $string): string
{
    $formattedValue = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1255',  $string);
    return $this->isHebrew($string) ? strrev($formattedValue) : $formattedValue;
}
```

And this is how I'm setting the FPDI/FPDF instance:

```
    $pdf = new Fpdi();
    $pdf->AddFont('OpenSansHebrew', '', 'OpenSansHebrew.php');
    $pdf->SetFont('OpenSansHebrew', '', 10);
```

Is there any way to solve this issue without using the `strrev()` method? It's a really bad solution for me.

Also, is there any way to make the document RTL? It generates it as LTR instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FPDI can work with TCPDF (which inherits from FPDF eventually) and has native support for RTL and also has built in support for the ‘free’ fonts, which support cp1255 encoding.

Just replace FPDF with TCPDF when using FPDI and it should solve your issues.